# How to solve quadratic programming problems with continuous variables and continous constraints by using quantum algorithms?

Tags: optimization, qaoa

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4ceZ.png) Here is my optimization problem I solve with classical optimization using DocPlex  but I want to solve using quadratic program using Qiskit and QAOA as solver `optimumeigen`.

The requirement is that I need to solve it with quantum algorithms. For solving QUBO problems, I could use QAOA. But for solving quadratic programming problems with only continuous variables, I don't know which quantum algorithm I could use. Or maybe this problem could be converted to a QUBO problem and then handled by QAOA. I'm not sure.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! Please add your code as text instead of using an image!

Answer (score 3):

## QUBO to QAOA/ADMM

To solve a continuous variable problem like yours, you should use the ADMM optimizer, and here is how you should do it.

#### 1. Keep your code in making the classical `cplex` model as it is, i.e

```python
import numpy as np
from docplex.mp.model import Model

ts=24 # simulation time

deltat = 1
Rgh = 5
Cgh = 6
uj = 3 #Given parameter

Tou_h = np.array([37.0, 38.5, 37.6, 36.6, 38.3, 37.9, 37.5, 38.6, 38.1, 37.3, 35.0, 36.3, 37.9, 36.4, 38.3, 37.7, 36.8, 35.8, 35.9, 36.0, 37.4, 37.3, 37.2, 37.5])
Tin_ref = np.array([26] * 10 + [24] * 14)

# Create a Docplex model
model = Model (name='temperature_minimization')

# Define decision variables
Tin_h = {t: model.continuous_var(name=f'Tin_h_{t}', lb=0) for t in range(ts)}
Uh_gh = {t: model.continuous_var (name=f'Uh_gh_{t}', lb=-15.6, ub=15.6) for t in range(ts)}

# Define constraints
for t in range(ts - 1):
  model.add_constraint (Tin_h[t + 1] ==Tin_h[t] - (deltat / Rgh * Cgh) * (Tin_h[t] - Tou_h[t]) - uj * Rgh * Uh_gh[t])



# Define an objective function
obj_function = model.sum((Tin_h[t] - Tin_ref[t]) ** 2 for t in range(ts))
model.minimize(obj_function)

# solving the model
model.solve()

# Display the results.
print("Objective Value:", model.objective_value)
for t in range(ts):
  print (f'Tin_h_{t} = {Tin_h[t].solution_value}, Uh_gh_{t} = {Uh_gh[t].solution_value}')
```

#### 2. Make sure to install required `qiskit` dependencies using:

```python
%pip install qiskit
%pip install cplex
%pip install docplex
%pip install qiskit_optimization
```

and then make the necessary imports for the `qiskit` package:

```python
from qiskit_optimization import QuadraticProgram
from qiskit_optimization.translators.docplex_mp import to_docplex_mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from docplex.mp.model import Model

from qiskit_algorithms import QAOA, NumPyMinimumEigensolver
from qiskit_algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit.primitives import Sampler
from qiskit_optimization.algorithms import CobylaOptimizer, MinimumEigenOptimizer
from qiskit_optimization.algorithms.admm_optimizer import ADMMParameters, ADMMOptimizer
from qiskit_optimization.translators import from_docplex_mp
```

Do note that this comes with a free version of `cplex` limited to solving $1000$ variables and $1000$ constraints. If your problem exceeds that, it won't solve it.

#### 3.  Import your model such that `qiskit` can understand it:

```python
# load from a Docplex model
mod = from_docplex_mp(model)
print(type(mod))
print()
print(mod.prettyprint())
```

you can check the details about your model like this, it displays all the linear variables, constants, the cost matrix, everything:

```python
print("constant:\t\t\t", mod.objective.constant)
print("linear dict:\t\t\t", mod.objective.linear.to_dict())
print("linear array:\t\t\t", mod.objective.linear.to_array())
print("linear array as sparse matrix:\n", mod.objective.linear.coefficients, "\n")
print("quadratic dict w/ index:\t", mod.objective.quadratic.to_dict())
print("quadratic dict w/ name:\t\t", mod.objective.quadratic.to_dict(use_name=True))
print(
    "symmetric quadratic dict w/ name:\t",
    mod.objective.quadratic.to_dict(use_name=True, symmetric=True),
)
print("quadratic matrix:\n", mod.objective.quadratic.to_array(), "\n")
print("symmetric quadratic matrix:\n", mod.objective.quadratic.to_array(symmetric=True), "\n")
print("quadratic matrix as sparse matrix:\n", mod.objective.quadratic.coefficients)
```

#### 4. Define the solvers you'll make use in solving the problem:

### Classical Solution

3-ADMM-H needs a QUBO optimizer to solve the QUBO subproblem, and a continuous optimizer to solve the continuous convex constrained subproblem. We first solve the problem classically:

we use the `MinimumEigenOptimizer` with the `NumPyMinimumEigenSolver` as a classical and exact `QUBO` solver and we use the `CobylaOptimizer` as a continuous convex solver. `3-ADMM-H` supports any other suitable solver available in Qiskit optimization.

```python
# define COBYLA optimizer to handle convex continuous problems.
cobyla = CobylaOptimizer()

# define QAOA via the minimum eigen optimizer
qaoa = MinimumEigenOptimizer(QAOA(sampler=Sampler(), optimizer=COBYLA()))

# exact QUBO solver as a classical benchmark
exact = MinimumEigenOptimizer(NumPyMinimumEigensolver())  # to solve QUBOs

# In case CPLEX is installed it can also be used for the convex problems, the QUBO,
# or as a benchmark for the full problem.
#
# cplex = CplexOptimizer()
```

#### Parameters

The `3-ADMM-H` are wrapped in class `ADMMParameters`. Customized parameter values can be set as arguments of the class.

```python
admm_params = ADMMParameters(
    rho_initial=1001, beta=1000, factor_c=900, maxiter=100, three_block=True, tol=1.0e-6
)
```

### Calling `3-ADMM-H` algorithm

To invoke the `3-ADMM-H` algorithm, an instance of the `ADMMOptimizer` class needs to be created. This takes `ADMM`-specific parameters and the subproblem optimizers separately into the constructor. The solution returned is an instance of the `OptimizationResult` class.

```python
# define QUBO optimizer
qubo_optimizer = exact
# qubo_optimizer = cplex  # uncomment to use CPLEX instead

# define classical optimizer
convex_optimizer = cobyla
# convex_optimizer = cplex  # uncomment to use CPLEX instead

# initialize ADMM with classical QUBO and convex optimizer
admm = ADMMOptimizer(
    params=admm_params, qubo_optimizer=qubo_optimizer, continuous_optimizer=convex_optimizer
)
```

5. Run the ADMM Solver for your problem

```python
# run ADMM to solve problem
result = admm.solve(mod)
```

### Classical Solver Result

The 3-ADMM-H solution can be then printed and visualized. The x attribute of the solution contains respectively, the values of the binary decision variables and the values of the continuous decision variables. The fval is the objective value of the solution.

```python
print(result.prettyprint())
```

It will give an output like this:

```python
objective function value: 1354.8542360685278
variable values: Tin_h_0=17.663029761048875, Tin_h_1=18.491408258771582, Tin_h_2=17.54786970153851, Tin_h_3=18.6364987479822, Tin_h_4=17.496378700095512, Tin_h_5=17.889667346808253, Tin_h_6=18.780309372587702, Tin_h_7=18.77321307560003, Tin_h_8=19.053101875660403, Tin_h_9=17.679025703596793, Tin_h_10=17.291236701341333, Tin_h_11=15.782773277770197, Tin_h_12=16.724625174535355, Tin_h_13=16.049729887057467, Tin_h_14=17.336396869454838, Tin_h_15=16.592380862605346, Tin_h_16=17.41354648393138, Tin_h_17=15.56175113614779, Tin_h_18=16.207082861820027, Tin_h_19=16.577530722487364, Tin_h_20=16.749629149997062, Tin_h_21=17.634392099010093, Tin_h_22=16.643925784908333, Tin_h_23=17.850220826905257, Uh_gh_0=1.4917323859345744, Uh_gh_1=1.6635899097804796, Uh_gh_2=1.5315951541140045, Uh_gh_3=1.5130881033538714, Uh_gh_4=1.6380704608781755, Uh_gh_5=1.5414504772033761, Uh_gh_6=1.4980483366588286, Uh_gh_7=1.5674837006146383, Uh_gh_8=1.6153569280847424, Uh_gh_9=1.5955305438626206, Uh_gh_10=1.51726529213077, Uh_gh_11=1.578588011327375, Uh_gh_12=1.739023005202363, Uh_gh_13=1.5422438102089115, Uh_gh_14=1.7266893175669118, Uh_gh_15=1.633865156236503, Uh_gh_16=1.674369304471061, Uh_gh_17=1.5760377940633585, Uh_gh_18=1.5507368470099077, Uh_gh_19=1.5423243137003648, Uh_gh_20=1.5930454713993645, Uh_gh_21=1.6392797196859752, Uh_gh_22=1.564066267740873, Uh_gh_23=2.1134932838436886
status: SUCCESS
```

#### 6. Quantum Solution

We now solve the same optimization problem with `QAOA` as a `QUBO` optimizer, running on the simulated quantum device. First, one needs to select the classical optimizer of the eigensolver `QAOA`. Then, the simulation backend is set. Finally, the eigensolver is wrapped into the `MinimumEigenOptimizer` class. A new instance of `ADMMOptimizer` is populated with `QAOA` as `QUBO` optimizer.

```python
# define QUBO optimizer
qubo_optimizer = qaoa

# define classical optimizer
convex_optimizer = cobyla
# convex_optimizer = cplex  # uncomment to use CPLEX instead

# initialize ADMM with quantum QUBO optimizer and classical convex optimizer
admm_q = ADMMOptimizer(
    params=admm_params, qubo_optimizer=qubo_optimizer, continuous_optimizer=convex_optimizer
)
```

then run ADMM to solve it

```python
# run ADMM to solve problem
result_q = admm_q.solve(mod)
```

#### Quantum Solver Results

Here we present the results obtained from the quantum solver. As in the example above x stands for the solution, and the `fval` is for objective value.

```
print(result.prettyprint())
```

You'll get an output like this:

```python
objective function value: 1354.8542360685278
variable values: Tin_h_0=17.663029761048875, Tin_h_1=18.491408258771582, Tin_h_2=17.54786970153851, Tin_h_3=18.6364987479822, Tin_h_4=17.496378700095512, Tin_h_5=17.889667346808253, Tin_h_6=18.780309372587702, Tin_h_7=18.77321307560003, Tin_h_8=19.053101875660403, Tin_h_9=17.679025703596793, Tin_h_10=17.291236701341333, Tin_h_11=15.782773277770197, Tin_h_12=16.724625174535355, Tin_h_13=16.049729887057467, Tin_h_14=17.336396869454838, Tin_h_15=16.592380862605346, Tin_h_16=17.41354648393138, Tin_h_17=15.56175113614779, Tin_h_18=16.207082861820027, Tin_h_19=16.577530722487364, Tin_h_20=16.749629149997062, Tin_h_21=17.634392099010093, Tin_h_22=16.643925784908333, Tin_h_23=17.850220826905257, Uh_gh_0=1.4917323859345744, Uh_gh_1=1.6635899097804796, Uh_gh_2=1.5315951541140045, Uh_gh_3=1.5130881033538714, Uh_gh_4=1.6380704608781755, Uh_gh_5=1.5414504772033761, Uh_gh_6=1.4980483366588286, Uh_gh_7=1.5674837006146383, Uh_gh_8=1.6153569280847424, Uh_gh_9=1.5955305438626206, Uh_gh_10=1.51726529213077, Uh_gh_11=1.578588011327375, Uh_gh_12=1.739023005202363, Uh_gh_13=1.5422438102089115, Uh_gh_14=1.7266893175669118, Uh_gh_15=1.633865156236503, Uh_gh_16=1.674369304471061, Uh_gh_17=1.5760377940633585, Uh_gh_18=1.5507368470099077, Uh_gh_19=1.5423243137003648, Uh_gh_20=1.5930454713993645, Uh_gh_21=1.6392797196859752, Uh_gh_22=1.564066267740873, Uh_gh_23=2.1134932838436886
status: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I don't know why the optimization using your code doesn't give a good result like a classical optimization using Pyomo and Ipopt as solvers. and if possible, I need to solve this problem using QAOA and VQE. not Cobyla as a classical solver that you use in part of the quantum solution.

Comment: This is QAOA, and QAOA uses classical optimizer to solve the problem. The classical and quantum results are exactly the same as you can see from the code.